# How do I react to input from multiple channels the same way in Go?

Tags: go, switch-statement, timeout

I have some concurrent code that has two different timeout intervals, one static and one dynamic. I want to react the same way to both of them. This is the gist of it:

```
select {
case <-time.After(staticTimeoutInterval):
    doSomething()
case <-time.After(dynamicTimeoutInterval):
    doSomething()
}
```

Is there any way to write doSomething() only once? It's strange that `select` isn't as flexible as `switch` in this respect.

Comment: You could `timeout := sTimeout; if dTimeout < timeout { timeout = dTimeout }` and only wait for `timeout`, or wait on a single channel that gets sent to after either timeout. What you have doesn't seem so bad to me, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your specific case you can use something like

```
timeout := min(staticTimeoutInterval, dynamicTimeoutInterval)

select {
case <-time.After(timeout):
    doSomething()
}

func min(a, b time.Duration) int {
    if a < b {
        return a
    }
    return b
}
```

About the seemingly inconsistent treatment of `switch` and `select` - while these statements have similar syntax, the purpose of `switch` is branched execution, while the purpose of `select` is communication.

If I can exaggerate:

- `switch` is about the part *after* the `case` expression - the `case` expression here is mostly a simple, side-effect free expression
- `select` is about the part *in* the `case` expression - the `case` expression here provides you with the important communication side effect and is not trivial to implement at all

Allowing fallthrough in `select` will allow you to save a couple of lines in some cases, but it will often make `select` statements harder to reason about. Given a similar choice in other situations, the Go creators have almost always gone with more verbose but simpler to understand.

Answer (score 0):

What you got looks right. `select` cases do not fall through. And if it did, it would remove clarity and result in the same number of lines of code.